# Is it possible to get timezone city information in SQL ? In below format to be precise

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to get the timezone of a machine in the following format using a stored procedure but all I have managed is the UTC+5.30 part yet.

[image]

My progress so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UspGetTimeZone]

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;


BEGIN

DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50),
        @DetailedTimeZone VARCHAR(50)

set @DetailedTimeZone = (SELECT  
    SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AS SYSDATETIMEOFFSET ) 



DECLARE @CISDB TABLE
(
    TimeZone    NVARCHAR(100)
)

Insert Into @CISDB( TimeZone)
    VALUES ( 'UTC' + (SELECT SUBSTRING(@DetailedTimeZone , 29, 9) AS OFFSET))
    select * from @CISDB

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This info is saved into registry,and you can read these data via using `xp_regread`

so I hope next query helps you:-

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UspGetTimeZone]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN

DECLARE @TimeStandared VARCHAR(50)
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
'TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeStandared OUT

DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50),
        @keyname varchar(200)
set @keyname = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\' + @TimeStandared
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',@keyname, 'Display',@TimeZone OUT
SELECT @TimeZone

END
```